# misleading docs - $evalAsync doesn't always guarantee at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) for the `$evalAsync` method states that:

> The $evalAsync makes no guarantees as to when the expression will be
>   executed, only that:
>
> - at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression
>     execution.

By reading source code I find this statement incorrect. Let me explain my observations. Application code can be executed either from the async queue, or as a watch callback. Here is the simplified relevant part of the digest function:

```
// process async queue
while (asyncQueue.length) {
    try {
        asyncTask = asyncQueue.shift();
        // application code can be executed from here - mostly promise callbacks
        asyncTask.scope.$eval(asyncTask.expression, asyncTask.locals);
    }
}

// process watchers
do {
    if ((watchers = current.$$watchers)) {
        length = watchers.length;
        while (length--) {
            try {
                watch = watchers[length];
                if (watch) {
                    if ((value = watch.get(current)) !== (last = watch.last)) {
                        dirty = true;
                        lastDirtyWatch = watch;
                        watch.last = watch.eq ? copy(value, null) : value;
                        // application code can be executed from here - watch callbacks
                        watch.fn(value, ((last === initWatchVal) ? value : last), current);
```

From this implementation you can see that if `$evalAsync` is called from the code that is executed from the async queue, the code will remain inside `while (asyncQueue.length)` loop **before** proceeding to the watchers, since `$evalAsync` pushes to asyncQueue another callback and the condition `asyncQueue.length` will return `true`. So it seems that the above statement is correct **only** if your code is being executed as a watch callback.

Is my understanding correct?

Here is the code to demonstrate the problem:

```
$q.when().then(function() {
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
        console.log('from eval async');
    });

    $scope.$watch('some', function() {
        console.log('from watcher');
    });
});
```

Here the callback inside `$evalAsync` will be executed earlier than $watch callback, while I expected it to execute after at least one digest takes place.

Comment: Your example is hard to follow. Any way, no, the docs are right.  You can check what $evalAsync does in the sources. The code will be executed immediately if it runs on digest. Or it will be executed with a digest on the next tick (similarly to $timeout(..., 0)).

Comment: @estus, I added an example. I expected it to run after at least one digest, but it's executed before any dirty checking occurs. On the second thought it guarantees at least one $digest cycle *after* the expression, not *before*. So probably I got confused at that.

Comment: It guarantees that the expression will be run during digest, either immediately or on the next tick. In your last example this happens inside `then` callback. $q promise chains are executed on digest.

Comment: @estus, yes, but my point was different. Anyways, I found what I got confused at. Thanks :)